# Best way to import large amounts of data (Csv vs xls vs xlsx vs ?)

Tags: php, import

I have a php application that needs to work on many configurations of php with as little requirements outside of the code igniter framework as possible.

I have an import function right now that uses .csv files. Csv is pretty good as if is cross platform. But people have trouble with it when using excel. It also can't display chiense characters correctly.

Then there is .xls and .xlsx files. There are libraries for these but often require php_zip

What option should I choose that works with many php installs and is good for display and import?

Comment: Is this a one off event, in-frequent or daily?

Comment: CSV like you said would be my first choice - if its tabular data it can't get any simpler. What's the issues in Excel? I'm sure the Chinese symbol issue could be resolved with the correct charset.

Answer (score 0):

there may be chances of information lost in the export to CSV.
 It will only save the values of the cells - not their formatting informations.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way you'll read an .xlsx file without unzipping it, which means you'll need a zip lib.

PHPExcel handles several formats of excel files, but it can be a bit resource hungry.

http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/

XLSX2CSV  is less resource intensive, but only reads one page of multi-page worksheets, doesn't read parse formulas and doesn't handle .xls files.

http://davidacollins.com/weblog/xlsx2csv